# Deploying Laravel to Elastic Beanstalk: "failed to open stream: Permission denied"

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Sometimes when I deploy a Laravel project to AWS Elastic Beanstalk I'm faced with an annoying error saying that the log file cannot be opened:

```
The stream or file "/var/app/current/storage/logs/laravel-2020-10-21.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

In my eb deploy.config file I have a statement which, in theory, should fix things, but doesn't:

```
files:
  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/99_make_storage_writable.sh":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      #!/usr/bin/env bash
      echo "Making /storage writeable..."
      chmod -R 755 /var/app/current/storage

      if [ ! -f /var/app/current/storage/logs/laravel.log ]; then
          echo "Creating /storage/logs/laravel.log..."
          touch /var/app/current/storage/logs/laravel.log
          chown webapp:webapp /var/app/current/storage/logs/laravel.log
      fi
```

This is because it's not referencing the daily log file.

I have an `.ebignore` file in place which explicitly prevents local logs from being deployed, so it isn't the presence of an existing log file that's causing problems:

```
/storage/logs/*
```

The issue is that Laravel is creating the daily log as `root` so it cannot be written to by the normal user (`webapp`).

I just don't know why it's doing it?

Comment: Different ownership can usually be attributed to _how_ the log file was original generated. If you have a `CRON` running the scheduler, and it runs into an error, the `.log` file will be created as `root`. If the webserver encounters a logged error, it will be created with `webapp` (or similar based on your config). If you can get both of those processes using the same or a compatible user/group/permissions set, then there won't be conflicts. (At least this is what I've come across before; not sure if it applies to EB)

Comment: Would another solution be to delete the log file and directory when deploying to EB and letting it create it when it's already deployed?

Comment: @FabricioG No log files are being deployed (quote: "I have an .ebignore file in place which explicitly prevents local logs from being deployed"). The problem is that different processes, with different permissions, are trying to write to the same logfile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to allow each process to create its own log file. That way each process will have the correct permissions to write to it.

You can do this in the `config/logging.php` file and adding the process name (`php_sapi_name()`) to the file name:

```
    'daily' => [
        'driver' => 'daily',
        'path' => storage_path('logs/' . php_sapi_name() . '-laravel.log'),
        'level' => 'debug',
        'days' => 14,
    ],
```

Now each process will be able to write to its own file and there will be no permission problems.

**Important Note:** The above example uses "Daily", but make sure you make the change to right logging channel for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set storage folder permissions to this

```
chmod -R gu+w storage/
chmod -R guo+w storage/
```

Comment: This, by itself, doesn't solve the problem. This is a CD environment.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else stumbles upon this one, and can't solve it despite all the great solutions, one other thing that causes the original problem "could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied" is that it seems like the  log file is being written by the root user, not the ec2-user or webapp, which means no matter how much the right chmod or chown is done, we can't touch the file.
So the workaround to that is to make sure the log file is saved with the user id and then it will be different files.

Add ".get_current_user()." to the storage_path

config/logging.php

```
'single' => [
        'driver' => 'single',
        'path' => storage_path('logs/'.get_current_user().'laravel.log'),
        'level' => env('LOG_LEVEL', 'debug'),
    ],

    'daily' => [
        'driver' => 'daily',
        'path' => storage_path('logs/'.get_current_user().'laravel.log'),
        'level' => env('LOG_LEVEL', 'debug'),
        'days' => 14,
    ],
```

Further though, one can discuss why log files are stored on a Beanstalk instance as it will anyway be overwritten the next time, so I would advice Horizon, S3 storage or whatever else, but that's a different topic. I guess you just want to solve the issue. I spent like a week until I found out the root user wrote the file first...

You can check who owns the file if you can SSH in to the Beanstalk instance "eb ssh". Then go to the folder var/app/current/storage/logs then write "ls -la" (which will list permissions). Then you can see that the root user has written the file once first and then has rights to it. I tried to change predeploy and postdeploy settings but didn't work. Writing it as a separate file name worked fine.